# Error al exportar a excel con PHPExcel

Tags: php, sql, excel

Al tratar de exportar el archivo me aparece el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\String.php on line 526

Este es el codigo con el cual se genera el archivo xls, ya descargue de nuevo el PHPExcel y siempre me da el mismo error

```
<?php 
require_once 'functions/excel.php';

activeErrorReporting();
noCli();

require_once '../PHPEXCEL/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'functions/conexion.php';
require_once 'functions/getAllListsAndVideos.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Developero")
               ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
               ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
               ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
               ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
               ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
               ->setCategory("Test result file");

$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial')
                                          ->setSize(10);            

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'codigo');

$informe = getAllListsAndVideos();
$i = 2;
while($row = $informe->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue("A$i", $row['codigo']);
$i++;
}

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Informe de vídeos');

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

getHeaders();

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Comment: Versión de PHPExcel que estás usando? Versión de PHP? Y pues, nada tiene que ver acá la etiqueta `sql`, qué opinas?

Comment: PHP Version 8.0.12
PHPExcel, 1.8.1
Disculpas por la etiqueta, la coloque porque en realidad estoy trantando de exportar una consulta sql

Comment: Si uno va al repo oficial de PHPExcel, encuentra que el proyecto está archivado y su última versión es de 2015. Es altamente probable que no funcione bien con PHP8. Y si usas [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)?? Es más, ni siquiera [funcionaba](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/716) con PHP > 7.1

Comment: PD. De dónde descargabas PHPExcel sin pasar por el repo oficial? Ten cuidado con los lugares de los que obtienes las dependencias.

Comment: Deacuerso bro, muchas gracias, disculpa pero soy principiante en esto

Comment: Todos lo somos en alguna cosa, alguna vez. Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: bro intente instalarlo del encale que dejaste pero me aparece un error
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Package phpoffice/phpspreadsheet at version ^1.19.0 has requirements incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extens
  ions and Composer version:
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.20.0 requires ext-gd * but it is not present.

ya Intente instalar la version 1.20.0

Comment: ya lo resolvi, seria de descomentar en el archivo, php.ini la linea donde dice;extension=gd

Answer (score 3):

Dejamos esto como respuesta:

Si uno va al [repo oficial](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/) de PHPExcel, encuentra que el proyecto está archivado (dice DEAD en el README xD) y su última versión es de 2015. Es altamente probable que no funcione bien con PHP8. Y si usas [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)??

Es más, PHPExcel [ni siquiera funcionaba](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/716) con PHP > 7.1

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, el error era idéntico:

Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in ReferenceHelper.php Line 884.

Edité las líneas 884 y 885 del programa ReferenceHelper.php de la carpeta de PHPExcel, cambiando los índices {0} por [0] y listo. Ya todo me funcionó. Mi versión de PHP es 8.0.24, sobre openSUSE 15.4.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).